# Replacing View using ng-view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ng-view

When the view change its replace the previous view in ng-view. but its not changing. it showing the template data which is "context".

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.service('datapass', function () {

    this.name = "name";

});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when("/name", {

        template: 'Context',
        controller: 'front_controller'
    })
    .when("/detail", {
        template: 'My Name is Awais Saleem',
        controller: 'main_controller'
    })
    .otherwise("/name");

});

app.controller("front_controller", function ($scope, datapass,$location) {
    $scope.url = datapass.name;
    $scope.changeView = function () {

        $scope.url = datapass.name = (datapass.name == "name") ? "detail" : "name";
      
    };

});

app.controller("main_controller", function ($scope, datapass,$location) {
    $scope.url = datapass.name;
  
    $scope.changeView = function () {

        $scope.url = datapass.name = (datapass.name == "name") ? "detail" : "name";
       
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp">

    <a ng-click="changeView()" href="#!{{url}}">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </a>
 
</body>
```

When i click on the "context" then it should show the other page data, like "My Name is Awais Saleem" and i click on "My name is..." then it show the "Context".
Basically i want to replace the previous view.

Comment: Try using `ng-href` instead of `href`.

Comment: Not Working 
But it work when i add ng-controller in body tag.

Comment: also it should be `href="#!/{{url}}"`

Comment: Still Not Working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller defined are only accessible inside the `<div ng-view></div>` element, however, you are trying to use it in the parent tag (`<a>`). Therefore the controllers and its function are not recognized in the parent tag. Hence, here the `<a>` tag should be inside the template.

Also Instead of using a `href`, the better way would be to use `$location.path()`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.service('datapass', function() {

  this.name = "name";

});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when("/name", {

      template: '<a ng-click="changeView()" href="">Context</a>',
      controller: 'front_controller'
    })
    .when("/detail", {
      template: '<a ng-click = "changeView()" href="">My Name is Awais Saleem</a>',
      controller: 'main_controller'
    })
    .otherwise("/name");

});

app.controller("front_controller", function($scope, datapass, $location) {
  $scope.changeView = function() {

    datapass.name = (datapass.name == "name") ? "detail" : "name";
    
    $location.path("/"+datapass.name);

  };

});

app.controller("main_controller", function($scope, datapass, $location) {

  $scope.changeView = function() {

    datapass.name = (datapass.name == "name") ? "detail" :"name";
    
    $location.path("/"+datapass.name);

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp">

  
    <div ng-view></div>
  

</body>
```

Comment: Very Good Explanation

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because `$scope.url` is only recognized in its controller, and since you don't have any controller in the HTML page, it doesn't know what that means.

A quick and dirty solution would be to add it to the `$rootScope`, but a better solution would be to add a parent state with a controller, and then all the states will have that functionality also.

Comment: But i am specifying the controller in the routing with its template, and to share data between controller i am using 'datapass' service.